# Is there a way to have a button run multiple functions in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I'm trying to have a button perform a sign out and change a boolean to false with one button. Is there any way to do this is or something similar in SwiftUI?

```
Button(action: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()!.signOut, self.settings.settingsView.toggle()) {
           ZStack {
               Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
               Text("Sign Out")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                     .font(Font.system(size: 25))
                        }
                   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to pass multiple arguments into `action` you can just execute the closure and have it do as many things as you want.  That would look more like this:

```
Button(action: {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()!.signOut
    self.settings.settingsView.toggle()
}) {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
             .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
             .cornerRadius(5)
             .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
        Text("Sign Out")
             .foregroundColor(.primary)
             .font(Font.system(size: 25))
     }
}
```