# In SwiftUI can I create two actions from one button? I want two random colors

Tags: swift, button, random, colors

I want a single button to change two color swatches to random colors. I have found code for changing one swatch.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMr4rv4rk98&feature=emb_logo
[@State private var randomColor1 = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.1, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMiVz.png)

But get an error when I try to make two random colors "consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'"

Searching for two actions from one button, this seems to imply it's not possible but instead just "execute the closure":
[Is there a way to have a button run multiple functions in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274125/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-button-run-multiple-functions-in-swiftui)

And here is my code:

```
    @State private var randomColor1 = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.1, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
@State private var randomColor2 = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.0, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack{
            HStack {
               Rectangle()
                   .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
                   .foregroundColor(Color(randomColor1))
               Rectangle()
                   .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
                   .foregroundColor(Color(randomColor2))
           }
            Button(action: {
                self.randomColor1 = UIColor(
                    red:.random(in: 0...1),
                    green: .random(in: 0...1),
                    blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                    alpha: 1))
            
                self.randomColor2 = UIColor(
                    red:.random(in: 0...1),
                    green: .random(in: 0...1),
                    blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                    alpha: 1)
                )
            }, label: {
               Text("Make 2 Random colors")
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an extra bracket mistake. Copy below code.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack{
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(randomColor1))
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(randomColor2))
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.randomColor1 = UIColor(
                    red:.random(in: 0...1),
                    green: .random(in: 0...1),
                    blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                    alpha: 1) //<- Here
                
                self.randomColor2 = UIColor(
                red:.random(in: 0...1),
                green: .random(in: 0...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                alpha: 1)
                //<- Here
            }, label: {
                Text("Make 2 Random colors")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Raja, that worked. I should have caught that myself but I was just in the mindset that it wasn't possible. Appreciate you taking look.

Comment: Glad to help you, you can accept the answer if it’s helpful

Comment: Ha! I did it, you did it, we did it! Ha ha, kidding but that was literally my first time accepting an answer (and even asking a question on stack overflow)